# How to send HTML text in the body of Rest API callout

Tags: rest-api, html

I am trying to send HTML text in the request body for Rest API callout. I came to know that you cannot use Escape quotation marks used around HTML attributes like  as it breaks the JSON body. In Apex we cannot escape it by writing it like </ br> as it gives compilation error in class. How should I get around this situation so as to send HTML text without breaking JSON?
Below is the HTML text that I want to send in the body

```
<b>Dear '+app.Approver_Name__r.Name+'</b></br></br>You have been assigned an offer for approval. </br></br><b>Main-Offer Name: </b>'+app.Main_Offer_Name__r.Name+' </br><b>Main Offer Description :</b>'+app.Main_Offer_Name__r.MO_Main_Offer_Description__c+'</br><b>MO-Cost Price: </b>'+app.Main_Offer_Name__r.Tot_Cost_Calc__c+'</br><b>MO-Sales Price: </b>'+app.Main_Offer_Name__r.Tot_SalesPrice_Calc__c+'</br><b>MO-Total Margin %: </b>'+app.Main_Offer_Name__r.Tot_MarginPercent_Calc__c+'</br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your HTML is wrong. It's `<br />`, not `</br>`. The `</tag>` means to close an open tag (`<tag>`), while `<tag />` means "there is no content", and is semantically equal to `<tag></tag>`.

Second, you simply need to `JSON.serialize(htmlString)` to make your string JSON-safe.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this silly mistake. I have corrected it. I tried using JSON.serialize(htmlString) but it resulted in 403 status code from Webservice.